# Where to find definition of window message WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM (0x92)

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, window-messages

I'm writing a hook dll, which handles window drawing messages.
I found for Vista and above, some unknown message id are received by the hook dll, specifically 0x90 ~ 0x95.
I did some googling and found an [msdn link](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsapps/en-US/f677f319-9f02-4438-92fb-6e776924425d/windowproc-and-messages-0x90-0x91-0x92-0x93) and [this](http://blog.airesoft.co.uk/2009/11/wm_messages/), which told me what message they're:

```
#define WM_UAHDESTROYWINDOW 0x0090
#define WM_UAHDRAWMENU 0x0091
#define WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM 0x0092
#define WM_UAHINITMENU 0x0093
#define WM_UAHMEASUREMENUITEM 0x0094
#define WM_UAHNCPAINTMENUPOPUP 0x0095
```

But I can't find definition of macro `WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM` in any header files, the compiler complains about "undefined symbols". I did a global search on "WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM" but found nothing.

At present I'm using 0x92 to handle this message.
My question is: how to nicely replace hard-coded 0x92 with a Windows-defined macro?

Comment: Usually, if you can't find documentation for Windows messages then they are internal Windows messages not intended for outside use. ie. use at your own risk.

Comment: FYI I've documented what these messages do and the structures associated with them here https://github.com/adzm/win32-custom-menubar-aero-theme after some trial and error. They are used to draw the menubar when using themes.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> how to nicely replace hard-coded 0x92 with a Windows-defined macro?

Obviously, your installed version of the Win32 SDK does not have the macros, so you can't use them.  But you have the `#define` values, so just copy/paste them directly into your own code.  If you want, you can wrap them in an `#ifdef` so that if you ever upgrade to an SDK version that has them natively, the native macros will be used, otherwise the compiler will keep using your manual ones.

```
#ifndef WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM
#define WM_UAHDRAWMENUITEM 0x0092
#endif
```

Comment: I think I'll just use integer 0x92, and leave a comment with it.